# ¿Cómo utilizar los MessageButtons?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una busqueda de clientes:

```
string cadsql = "Select * from clientes where [Cedula o RNC]='" + txtcedula.Text + "'";

        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadsql, con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
        if (leer.Read() == true)
        {
            txtnombre.Text = leer["Nombres"].ToString();
            txtapellido.Text = leer["Apellidos"].ToString();
            txttelefono.Text = leer["Telefono"].ToString();
            txtcelular.Text = leer["Celular"].ToString();
            txtdispositivo.Enabled = true;
            txtmodelo.Enabled = true;
            txtcolor.Enabled = true;
            txtcondiciones.Enabled = true;
            txtreparaciones.Enabled = true;
            txtcedula.Enabled = false;
            txtdispositivo.Select();


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cliente no Encontrado.");
            txtcedula.Clear();
            txtcedula.Select();

        }
        con.Close();
```

Quiero que cuando no encuentre clientes que me tire un mensaje al usuario de si desea registrar un nuevo cliente, si presiona que si que me abra un formulario, si presiona que no que limpie los campos.

Comment: Samuel, me parece que tu pregunta es muy amplia, ¿qué tipo de formulario? ¿Usas WebForms o WinForms? ¿Nos podrías mostrar algún intento de lo que deseas realizar?

Comment: winforms @Flxtr LA EDITE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes mostrar un mensaje `YES`/`NO` con un `DialogResult`

```
string cadsql = "Select * from clientes where [Cedula o RNC]='" + txtcedula.Text + "'";

SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadsql, con);
con.Open();

SqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
if (leer.Read() == true)
{
    txtnombre.Text = leer["Nombres"].ToString();
    txtapellido.Text = leer["Apellidos"].ToString();
    txttelefono.Text = leer["Telefono"].ToString();
    txtcelular.Text = leer["Celular"].ToString();
    txtdispositivo.Enabled = true;
    txtmodelo.Enabled = true;
    txtcolor.Enabled = true;
    txtcondiciones.Enabled = true;
    txtreparaciones.Enabled = true;
    txtcedula.Enabled = false;
    txtdispositivo.Select();
}
else
{
    DialogResult mensaje = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea agregar un nuevo cliente?", "Cliente no encontrado", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if(mensaje == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //Se va a mandar llamar el evento del botón NUEVO
    }
    else if (mensaje == DialogResult.No)
    {
        //Aquí hará las acciones necesarias para manejar la respuesta NO
    }
    txtcedula.Clear();
    txtcedula.Select();
}
con.Close();
```

## Recomendación:

No utilices consultas dinámicas, así como está tu código es suceptible a [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Siempre accede a la base de datos a través de consultas parametrizadas o *Stored Procedures*, aquí te dejo la página de [la documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ff648339.aspx) (***Paso 3. Uso de parámetros con SQL dinámico***) para que revises cuales son las mejores prácticas y mejores la seguridad de tu aplicación..

Comment: muchas gracias hermano por el aporte y las recomendaciones

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor De nada mi hermano :D